# How can I customize the view shown during drag and drop?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have drag and drop setup on my UWP app, and I'd like to customize the view that the user drags. Currently it's the exact same as the `ListViewItem`, but that has a `Border`(providing a background and rounded edges) I don't want to show in the dragging view.

It's just a simple `CanDragItems` and `AllowDrop` with `DragItemsStarting`, `DragEnter` and `Drop` events hooked.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: It's just a simple `CanDragItems` and `AllowDrop` with `DragItemsStarting`, `DragEnter` and `Drop` events hooked. I don't know what else to share.

Comment: Can you share a gif/screenshot?

Comment: What border? The boder of `ListViewitem`? An arrow in drag view?

Comment: @Sunteen it is a `Border` which is the only child of my `ListViewItem`, it provides rounded corners and a background

Comment: @vrwim So you want your `ListViewItem` has the border, but the drag UI will not has the border?

Comment: @Sunteen yes, that is exactly it

Comment: Any updates? Have you already resolved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but that has a Border(providing a background and rounded edges) I don't want to show in the dragging view.

To remove the `Bolder` of the `ListviewItem`, you don't need to custom the dragging view, you can just set the `Bolder` element's child element to `CanDrag`, after setting the `CanDrag` property for the `Bolder` child element such as `TextBlock`, you will not see the `Bolder` effects when dragging the item. Code example as follows:

```
    <ListView x:Name="SourceListView"
              Header="SourceListView"
              SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Pink"
                        BorderBrush="Gray"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}"  DragStarting="TextBlock_DragStarting" CanDrag="True"  />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

> I'd like to customize the view that the user drags.

If you still want to custom your drag UI,there is an existing class [DragUIOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.draguioverride.aspx) you can directly use for custom your Drag view.
For example you don't want to show the arrow in the drag view, you can set the  `IsGlyphVisible` property in the `DragOver` event like this:

```
 private void cnvDrop_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {           
    e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = false;
 }
```

And the offical sample is [XamlDragAndDrop](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop/cs), the scenario2 shows details about DragUI's customization.