# Xamarin forms 5.0 CollectionView Drag appearence multiple items

Tags: xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop, collectionview, multipleselection

Good afternoon.
I am using a CollectionView in Xamarin forms 5.0
I already succed to "transfert" 2 or more items from one CollectionView to an other one in the same window using `SelectionMode="Multiple"`.
For my test, i just use and customize a good example founded on the web: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/DragAndDropXFSample
What i'm trying to do concern the appearance of the dragged items.
Because i add a `DragGestureRecognizer` inside my `CollectionView.ItemTemplate.DataTemplate`
on my first collection view and a `DropGestureRecognizer` inside my `CollectionView.ItemTemplate.DataTemplate` second collection view, the drag & drop functionnality work well.
But, the animation draw only the item i touched, not all the selected ones.
Does anybody has an idea to manage that ?
Is it even possible?

Anyway, thanks for reading and maybe your help ;-)

The xaml page:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <ContentPage
        x:Class="DragAndDropXFSample.EventsPage"
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Padding="20,40" BackgroundColor="Black">
                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    Text="Hi John" />
                <Label Text="Your schedule Today" />
                <Frame Margin="0,20,0,0" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <CollectionView
                            x:Name="EventsCollection"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Events}"
                            SelectionMode="Multiple">
                            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                                <Label Text="You have no events" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <GridItemsLayout
                                    HorizontalItemSpacing="10"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Span="2"
                                    VerticalItemSpacing="10" />
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Frame
                                        Padding="0"
                                        BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"
                                        HasShadow="False">
                                        <Frame.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Frame">
                                                <!--  To visualy show the selection to the user  -->
                                                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                                                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="CadetBlue" />
                                                                    <Setter TargetName="uiTime" Property="Label.FontAttributes" Value="Italic" />
                                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Frame.Style>
                                        <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,0" Spacing="10">
                                            <Label
                                                x:Name="uiTime"
                                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                FontSize="Large"
                                                Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" />
                                            <Label FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                            <Label
                                                FontSize="Caption"
                                                Text="{Binding Location, StringFormat='At {0}'}"
                                                TextColor="White" />
    
                                            <StackLayout
                                                Margin="-10,0"
                                                Padding="5"
                                                BackgroundColor="#66000000"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image
                                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                    Source="ic_edit" />
                                                <Label
                                                    FontSize="Caption"
                                                    Text="Edit"
                                                    TextColor="White"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
    
                                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <DragGestureRecognizer DragStartingCommand="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DragStartingCommand, Source={x:Reference EventsCollection}}" DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, Source={x:Reference EventsCollection}}" />
                                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Frame>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
    
    
                        <CollectionView x:Name="EventsCollection2" ItemsSource="{Binding Events2}">
                            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                                <Label Text="You have no events" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <GridItemsLayout
                                    HorizontalItemSpacing="10"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Span="2"
                                    VerticalItemSpacing="10" />
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Frame
                                        Padding="0"
                                        BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"
                                        HasShadow="False">
                                        <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,0" Spacing="10">
                                            <Label
                                                x:Name="uiTime2"
                                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                FontSize="Large"
                                                Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" />
                                            <Label FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                            <Label
                                                FontSize="Caption"
                                                Text="{Binding Location, StringFormat='At {0}'}"
                                                TextColor="White" />
    
                                            <StackLayout
                                                Margin="-10,0"
                                                Padding="5"
                                                BackgroundColor="#66000000"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image
                                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                    Source="ic_edit" />
    
                                                <Label
                                                    FontSize="Caption"
                                                    Text="Edit"
                                                    TextColor="White"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <DropGestureRecognizer DropCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DropOverList2Command, Source={x:Reference EventsCollection2}}" />
                                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Frame>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

The view model class :

```cs
    public class EventsPageViewModel
        {
            private IList<Event> _dragEvent;
    
            /// <summary>
            /// It's a Command<IList<object>> beacause of the Selectionmode.Multiple
            /// </summary>
            public ICommand DragStartingCommand => new Command<IList<object>>((param) =>
             {
                 _dragEvent = new List<Event>(param.Cast<Event>());
             });
    
         
            public ICommand DropOverList2Command => new Command(() =>
            {
                foreach (var e in _dragEvent)
                {
                    if (Events.Contains(e))
                    {
                        Events.Remove(e);
                        Events2.Add(e);
                    }
                }
                   
                    
            });
    
         
    
            public ObservableCollection<Event> Events { get; }
    
            public ObservableCollection<Event> Events2 { get; }
    
         
    
            public EventsPageViewModel()
            {
                Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>()
                {
                    {new Event("Go for a walk", "Home", DateTime.Now.AddHours(3), Color.OrangeRed) },
                    {new Event("Finish PR", "Work", DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), Color.ForestGreen) },
                    {new Event("Watch a movie", "Home", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(40), Color.LightSkyBlue) },
                };
    
                Events2 = new ObservableCollection<Event>()
                {
                    {new Event("Go for a walk2", "Home", DateTime.Now.AddHours(3), Color.GreenYellow) }
                    
                };
            }
        }
```

**Edit :**
I cannot make video but i 've made some screenshots.
Initial state:
Nothing selected, the top collection view is the source, and the bottom collection view is the dest

[image: initial state]

I select the first item in the top collection view

[image: first item selected]

I select a second item in the top CollectionView 
[image: first and second items selected]

I start dragging by touching and moving the first selected item 
[image: drag start]

the expected result would be something like :

[image: expeted result]

**EDIT:**
I find something interresting called `Windows.UI.Xaml.DragEventArgs.DragUIOverride`
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179297/how-can-i-customize-the-view-shown-during-drag-and-drop/37207358#37207358)    but apparently it is for uwp, does anybody know if there is an equivalent for Android/iOS ?   
 Thanks for your time

Comment: `But, the animation draw only the item i touched, not all the selected ones.` What do you mean by words `the selected ones` ? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure, my collection view has selectionmode.multiple so i can select multiple items.let say i select 3 item, what i try to do is that the drag preview  show these three items, not the one who start the drag event.

Comment: Can you make a short video explaining your problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, i cannot make a video but i've added some screenshots :) Is it more understandable?

Comment: Hey there, i find something interresting called `Windows.UI.Xaml.DragEventArgs.DragUIOverride`  
 [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179297/how-can-i-customize-the-view-shown-during-drag-and-drop/37207358#37207358)    but apparently it is for uwp, does anybody know if there is an equivalent for Android/iOS ?    Thanks for your time

Comment: Based on the code you posted,I could only select and drag one item in CollectionView not as you mentioned in the lasted sceenshot.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT  if you take a look at Frame.GestureRecognizers.DragGestureRecognizer in the xaml, you will see tha the command parameter is <br/> `DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, Source={x:Reference EventsCollection}}"` and in the view model, the corresponding command definition is <br/> `new Command<IList<object>>((param) => { _dragEvent = new List<Event>param.Cast<Event>());});`      As result, the command parameter does contains the selected items. The last screenshot is the expected result ;)